# Multithreading result into slower

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

Basically I havn't done multi-threaded programming earlier. Conceptually I am aware of it.

So started with some what coding with random number generation. Code is working but it produce slower result than single thread program. So wanted to know for loopholes in my code and how to improve performance.

so if I tr to generate 1-1500 numbers randomly, using single thread and 10 threads (or 5 threads). single thread execute faster. thread switching or locking seems to be taking time. so how to handle it?

```
pthread_mutex_t   map_lock;
std::set<int> numSet;
int randcount=0;

static void *thread_fun (void *arg)
{
    int randNum= *(int *)arg;
    int result;
    std::set<int> findItr;

        while (randcount !=  randNum -1 ) {
        result = rand ()%randNum;

        if (result == 0) continue;
             pthread_mutex_lock (&map_lock);
             const bool is_in = (numSet.find (result) != numSet.end ());
             if  (!is_in)
             {
                numSet.insert (result);
                printf (" %d\t", result);
                randcount++;
             }

             pthread_mutex_unlock (&map_lock);
        }

}
```

Comment: How are you running this? Is this compiled as some programming language?

Comment: The point of multithreading is not to do one thing faster but to do many things at the same time.  Your example is a poor reason to try multithreading, instead you should do (for example) multiple connections to a server.  Those are not serial processes but parallel.

Comment: Above is partial code written in C++ language. Which gets calls for every thread created using pthread_create.

Comment: @KevinDTimm I agree with you that example is really bad and not meant for parallel processing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the majority of your code blocks all parallel threads (because is between a *pthread_mutex_lock (&map_lock);* and a *pthread_mutex_unlock (&map_lock);* block), your code works like it was running sequentially only with the overhead of parallelisation.

Tip: try to only collect the results in your thread then pass them back to the main thread which will display them. Also if you don't access your set parallely but pass back partial lists from each thread you don't have to deal with concurrency slowing down your code.